# Add post class in custom loop (WP_QUERY)

Tags: php, wp-query, loop

Normally if I wanted to add a custom post class I would use the `post_class` filter.

However, when using a custom loop the `post_class` filter is not accessible.

I am trying to apply classes that will place posts into columns depending on the count. Here is the example code I would use when not using a custom loop;

```
    //Add Post Class Filter
add_filter('post_class', 'sk_post_class');

function sk_post_class($classes) {
    global $loop_counter;
    $classes[] = 'one-third';

    if (($loop_counter + 3) % 3 == 0) {
        $classes[] .= 'first';
    }

    $loop_counter++;
    return $classes;
}
```

Each post in my custom loop is wrapped with `<div class = "answers"></div>`. I am thinking that I need to be able to modify the code above to add classes to `<div class = "answers">` based on the loop counter.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to how I might be able to achieve this?

Comment: the `post_class` filter works fine in custom loops if you've used the `post_class` *function* correctly. edit your question to add your custom loop code with the `post_class` function.

Comment: Thanks milo, that lead me to the answer I have posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As milo stated, I need to use the `post_class` function to use the `post_class` filter.

By adding `<?php post_class(); ?>` to the div in my loop I was then able to successfully modify the post class. Below is my full code containing the `post_class` filter and the `post_class` function.

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class

```
          <?php


      //Call in the header
      get_header();


          //Add Post Class Filter
      add_filter('post_class', 'sk_post_class');

      function sk_post_class($classes) {
          global $loop_counter;
          $classes[] = 'one-third';

          if (($loop_counter + 2) % 2 == 0) {
              $classes[] .= 'first';
          }

          $loop_counter++;
          return $classes;
      }


      $args = array (
        'post_type'  => array( 'test' ),
      );

      $query = new WP_Query( $args );

      if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
          $query->the_post(); ?>

          <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"<?php post_class(); ?>>

              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

          </div>

      <?php }
      } else {
        echo 'No posts found';
      }

      // Restore original Post Data
      wp_reset_postdata();


       // Call in footer 
      get_footer();

      ?>
```